# Error getting values ​from JSON nested with spaces in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to get values ​​from a nested JSON, which contains keys with spaces.
I am having this error:

- Notice: Trying to get property 'Submit Date' of non-object in
  json.php on line 47
- Notice: Trying to get property 'Entry ID' of non-object in json.php
  on line 46

  ```
      {
           "entries": [
               {
                   "values": {
                              "Entry ID": "INC000000001",
                               "Submitter": "Remedy Application Service",
                               "Assigned Group": "TI WIN",
                               "Priority": "Medium",
                               "Submit Date": "2022-07-20T22:27:01.000+0000",
                               "Assignee": "Example asignee"
                               },
                    "_links": {
                              }
                }
                       ]

        }
  ```

My PHP Code

```
 <?php
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    foreach($data->entries as $entr)
    {
      
        foreach($entr->values as $valores)
         {
    
           $entry_id=$valores->{'Entry ID'};
           $submit_date=$valores->{'Submit Date'};
          }
    }
   ?>
```

print_r output:

```
Array
(
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [Entry ID] => INC000000001
                            [Submitter] => Remedy Application Service
                            [Assigned Group] => TI WIN
                            [Priority] => Medium
                            [Submit Date] => 2022-07-20T22:27:01.000+0000
                            [Assignee] => Example asignee
                         )
                 )
        )
)
```

Where is the error?

any method to get the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is inconsistent with your `print_r` output; in your code `$data` will be an object (because you have not specified the `$associative` parameter to `json_decode`) which looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [values] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Entry ID] => INC000000001
                            [Submitter] => Remedy Application Service
                            [Assigned Group] => TI WIN
                            [Priority] => Medium
                            [Submit Date] => 2022-07-20T22:27:01.000+0000
                            [Assignee] => Example asignee
                        )
                    [_links] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The `values` property of each entry in the `entries` array is an object, not an array, so you can't iterate it. Instead, just access the properties directly:

```
foreach($data->entries as $entr) {
    $entry_id=$entr->values->{'Entry ID'};
    $submit_date=$entr->values->{'Submit Date'};
    var_dump($entry_id, $submit_date);
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
string(12) "INC000000001"
string(28) "2022-07-20T22:27:01.000+0000"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SFgph#v7.4.30)